# How to find the equation of a line that makes an angle θ with another line with a known equation

Tags: geometry

> [A better explanation of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym4gE.jpg)

So I'm having a bit of a mathematical dilemma but I'm hoping someone can help me.

I want to know the equation of a line $g(x)$, and it shares an intersection $(9,3)$ with line $y=-0.25x + 5.25$. The intersection makes an angle of $38^\circ$. How might I work out the equation for $g(x)?$ Is there even enough to work with to make this possible?

You can assume that both lines are straight.

Comment: Given two lines $y=m_1x+n_1$ and $y=m_2x+n_2$, the angle between lines is given by the following formula $$\tan(\alpha)=\left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right|$$ As you can see there are two options. Find $m_2$, use the given point and find $n_2$.

Comment: so how would I do that in this situation?

Comment: You have $\alpha=38^{\circ},m_1=-0.25$. Put the values in formula and get $m_2$. If you need help with solving it, don't hesitate to ask ;)

Comment: Hi @Galc127! I am encountering a similar issue. Can you help me find a point (any) on the line in the direction indicated in the image?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use translation-rotation to transform the mobile endpoint first.

See this question (which I answered, so you should know how to prove the result): [On the rotation of points issue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901691/on-the-rotation-of-points-issue)

That gives you the method of rotating points about the *origin*. To make that apply here, first translate the endpoints so that the fixed endpoint would "become" the origin. So the mobile endpoint would become $(5-9,4-3) = (-4,1)$

Now apply that counterclockwise rotation transform to this new point:

$(-4,1)$ would become $(-4\cos 38^{\circ} - \sin 38^{\circ}, -4 \sin 38^{\circ} + \cos 38^{\circ})$

And then reverse that linear (translation) transform to get everything back into its rightful place on the plane:

$(-4\cos 38^{\circ} - \sin 38^{\circ}, -4 \sin 38^{\circ} + \cos 38^{\circ})$ would become $(9-4\cos 38^{\circ} - \sin 38^{\circ}, 3-4 \sin 38^{\circ} + \cos 38^{\circ})$

Finally, you have to do is find the equation of the line between that point and $(9,3)$

For that you can simply use $\displaystyle \frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1} = \frac{y- y_2}{x-x_2} $

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. I'm too young in this site to upvote posts yet but you have a theoretical upvote from me!

Comment: @notHalfBad I've corrected it. It's a slightly more involved procedure, but it's not that much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't the slightest idea.

So I make it up from scratch.

Lines have slopes. Slopes are like angles.  How do angles compare to slopes?

A slope is the "rise over the run" i.e. change in distance of the y value over the change in the x value.  That has to be proportional to $\sin/\cos$ or $\tan $ of the angle.

So $angle = \arctan slope $.

$Slope = \tan angle $.

That's just common sense.  So the angle of $y = -.25x +5.25$ is $\arctan -1/4 = -14$ degrees.

The angle of intersection is $38$  however the question if the intersection is $38$ more than $-14$ or less.

I'll do both.  If the line of intersection is $38$ degrees more, The line I want has angle of $38 -14 =24$ so the line has a slope of $\tan 24 =.45$.

The line has point $(9,3) $ and slope $.45$ so the equation of the line is $y -3 = .45 (x -9) $ or $y =.45 x -1.05$

If the angle of intersection is $38$ degrees less, I want an angle of $-14 -38=-52$ or a slope of $\tan _52 = -1.28$

So the equation is $y-3=-1.28 (x-9)$ or $y =-1.28x +14.52$